# Show that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a union of topological circles.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

On sketch of my idea is: $\mathbb{R}^2$ fails in being such union because of the origin. Now, If I make every coordinate plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I mean, the planes $z = 0, x = 0, y = 0$ then I can cover every of this plane and even more, I will include the origin.
I don't know if it is a good idea, any comments/sugestions will be very appreciate.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Open disks or closed disks?

Comment: by topological discs I mean closed curves without intersection.

Comment: If I were you I'd call them topological circles, but thanks for clarification.

Comment: Do you mean *disjoint* union of topological circles? Otherwise it's just trivial.

Comment: yes, topological circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is even possible to represent $\Bbb R^3$ as a disjoint union of *geometrical* circles (i.e. curves which are isometric to standard plane circle). The standard explicit construction has two steps:

1. Show that a two-punctured sphere (i.e. a sphere with two points removed) is a disjoint union of circles.
2. Let $S$ be the union of circles on $Oxy$ plane with unit radii and centers $(4k+1,0,0)$. Show that $\Bbb R^3\setminus S$ is a disjoint union of two-puntured spheres.

I don't know of an easier construction using topological circles, but I wouldn't be surprised to be told there is one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It is possible to cover $\Bbb R^2$ with one point removed by disjoint circles so that the uncovered point is not a center of either circle. I am capable of proving whole $\Bbb R^2$ is not a union of topological circles, but my proof in an essential way uses Jordan curve theorem and Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: Sorry, on my post there was to many typos. Thanks, I will think about it.